# ImageView image populated Upside Down

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am trying to populate an image in an ImageView using Picasso, but the image is populated upside down or rotated 90 degrees. Below is the code for populating the image. This is happening with one few images.

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(NetworkConstants.IMAGE_PREFIX + flag.get(position).getFilePath())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
                    .resize(400, 400)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(busines_img);
```

The outcome of this code is:

[image: Only this picture is upside down.]

[Url For the Image](http://travelouder.com/backend/resources/images/post/1531159945_391041288.png)

This same picture comes properly in IOS devices.
Thank in Advance for you help.

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42411772/4239410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug because the image orientation is wrong in your photo EXIF. This snippet might help you: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/c1d60eea6cf7116fa547e573d992794a7ba82414/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/FileBitmapHunter.java

Comment: Thank you it helped me, but can you help as how to get exif information for a remote file.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know anything more about EXIFs and how to use them inside Android Studio. But for checking the actual information you can use this site https://www.get-metadata.com/ and upload your photos there and the site will tell you all the secrets of that photo.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **.rotate(180)** in your code.

Comment: Then all images will be rotated, the problem is just with one or two images.